# Converting from *.docx using redoc::dedoc corrupt

Tags: r, r-markdown, redoc

I have created a word file from an rmarkdown file using redoc output directly in RStudio and clicking "knit". This works fine.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  redoc::redoc
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## GitHub Documents

This is an R Markdown format used for publishing markdown documents to GitHub. When you click the **Knit** button all R code chunks are run and a markdown file (.md) suitable for publishing to GitHub is generated.

## Including Code

You can include R code in the document as follows:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

but trying to convert it back to Rmd it throws an error. Has anyone else had that?

```
redoc::dedoc(docx = "test.docx",overwrite = TRUE)

Error in convert_docx_to_md(docx, track_changes, wrap, verbose, md_only) : 
  lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rmarkdown/R/rmarkdown.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In convert_docx_to_md(docx, track_changes, wrap, verbose, md_only) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In convert_docx_to_md(docx, track_changes, wrap, verbose, md_only) :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```